# Listen for input while running

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to be able to control few parameters in a running code by typing input or even better simply by pressing keys. I have the following code that sort of does what I need but I wonder if this is the right approach.

```
import threading
import time

stuff = 'a'

def print_stuff():
    global stuff
    print(stuff)
    time.sleep(1.0)
    print_stuff()

def listen():
    global stuff
    stuff = input('What should I print?')
    listen()

t = threading.Thread(target=print_stuff)
t.start()
t = threading.Thread(target=listen)
t.start()
```

Would it be better to use Queue instead of the global `stuff`? Is there a way to run the main bit (body of `print_stuff()` in the above snippet without putting it into a function?

Comment: You use recursion with no return, you'll end up at some point with max recursion depth exception. You better put your functions into a while true loop instead.